# Where are webgrind profiling files stored in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, ubuntu, profiling, webgrind

I have setup xdebug and webgrind and I have generated several profiling files. Where are those generated files stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set where xdebug save profiling activity in you active php.ini
(ussually /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini) with

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = xdebug.out.%t
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
```

Which set both filename and folder (**xdebug.out.%t** and **/tmp**)
Dont forget to restart apache after saving php.ini

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```